# How to set lock screen photo using PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell

How do I set the lock screen from 'windows spotlight' to 'photo' and then set the photo to a specific image.

Here is what I tried:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization' -Name LockScreenImage -value "C:\Custom-Folder\wallpaper.jpg"
```

it gives me an error and says the Path does not exist.

Here is the error message:

```
Set-ItemProperty : Cannot find path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization' because it
does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Per ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (HKLM:\SOFTWARE\...Personalization:String) [Set-ItemProperty], I
   temNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetItemPropertyCommand
```

Comment: Note: This question is on topic in terms of content, OP is *not* asking how to set this, they are inquiring about the error received when setting the registry key property value.

Comment: OP what is the *exact* error you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure the registry key exists and if not create it first.

**Edit**

Thanks to [mklement0's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69776800/how-to-set-lock-screen-photo-using-powershell/69778505?noredirect=1#comment123346268_69778505) it is clear we shouldn't use `New-Item -Force` on a registry key because of the risk all content of an existing key will get destroyed.

That means we need a test to see if the key exists

```sh
$regKey = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization'
# create the key if it doesn't already exist
if (!(Test-Path -Path $regKey)) {
   $null = New-Item -Path $regKey
}

# now set the registry entry
Set-ItemProperty -Path $regKey -Name LockScreenImage -value "C:\Custom-Folder\wallpaper.jpg"
```

Because this is in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` you need to run this code as Administrator.

Comment: Instead of discarding the `New-Item` result, one could use it to streamline the code: `New-Item -Path $regKey -Force | Set-ItemProperty -Name LockScreenImage -value "C:\Custom-Folder\wallpaper.jpg"`.

Comment: Unfortunately, using `New-Item -Force` with a registry key effectively _wipes out any existing values_ of a preexisting key (the key is apparently _re-created_) - which is arguably a bug, given that a registry key is akin to a file-system _directory_, whose content should be preserved with `-Force`, not a file - see [GitHub issue #5444](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5444); /cc @zett42

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks for this warning. I wasn't aware of this bug before (always testing in the registry with dummy keys luckily..). Changed that in my answer now.

Comment: Thanks for updating, @Theo. Yes, it's an easy bug to miss, but with potentially destructive consequences - I hope they'll fix it some day...

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who ended up on this page looking for why that path can't be found, it is because the actual path is

```
HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Personalization.
```

'CurrentVersion' is missing from the original path.